# AlarmManager gets killed on app destroy

Tags: android, alarmmanager, repeat

I have the following problem: I register my alarm manager in `onCreate`, It gets executed each minute now. **However** if i kill the app via the `Android taskmanager` (so the app state is `destoyed`) the `AlarmReceiver` stops excecuting. Why?

My Code:

**AlarmReceiver**

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

private AlarmManager mAlarm;
private PendingIntent mAlarmIntent;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Intent service = new Intent(context, PortalPullService.class);

    startWakefulService(context, service);
}

public void setAlarm(Context context) {
    mAlarm = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
    mAlarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);

    int interval = context.getResources().getInteger(R.integer.update_interval_in_mins) * 60 * 1000;

    mAlarm.setInexactRepeating(
            AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
            SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + interval,
            interval,
            mAlarmIntent);

    ComponentName reciever = new ComponentName(context, AlarmBootReceiver.class);
    PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();

    pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(reciever,
            PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,
            PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
}

public void cancelAlarm(Context context) {
    if(mAlarm != null) {
        mAlarm.cancel(mAlarmIntent);
    }

    ComponentName reciever = new ComponentName(context, AlarmBootReceiver.class);
    PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();

    pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(reciever,
            PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
            PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
}
}
```

**PullService**

```
public class PortalPullService extends IntentService {

private static final String LOG_TAG = "PortalPullService";

public PortalPullService() {
    super(LOG_TAG);
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {


    //TODO make request to ** check if new Infos are available, then send notification

    Helper.sendNotification(this, "Test", "Testnotification"); //My test if this works

    AlarmReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
}

}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<receiver android:name=".PortalUpdate.AlarmReceiver" />

<service
        android:name=".PortalUpdate.PortalPullService"
        android:exported="false" />
```

The receiver gets registered via `new AlarmReceiver().setAlarm(this);`

I searched on sveral SO questions, but i can't find an answer... I don't know where is my fault...

Thanks in advance ;)

Comment: Yes, on my Huawei it gets killed...

Comment: "However if i kill the app via the Android taskmanager" -- perhaps Huawei modified the task manager to do a force-stop instead of a normal process termination. If so, there is nothing that you can do about it. You might use `adb shell dumpsys alarm` to examine your scheduled alarms before and after whatever you are doing to "kill the app".

Comment: @CommonsWare but my WhatsApp services doesn't get destroyed. So this can't be, or am i wrong?

Comment: You are not the developer of WhatsApp. You do not know how WhatsApp was implemented. Do not worry about WhatsApp. Worry about your app. Use `adb shell dumpsys alarm` to see if your alarms are getting removed when you "kill the app". Then, use `adb shell dumpsys alarm` to see if your alarms are getting removed when your process is simply killed (e.g., through the Android Monitor tool in Android Studio). That will go a long way towards isolating the source of your problem.

Comment: @CommonsWare the service disappears after i closed it...

Comment: That is expected behavior. Moreover, that is what the *user* wants. [Only have a service running when it is actively delivering value to the user](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/07/27/role-services.html). Waiting for `AlarmManager` is not actively delivering value to the user. If you are not going to follow my advice and try to track down whether your alarms are being deleted, that is your decision.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay it's a problem to install a debug version of your app on Huawei.

Because you can disable Background Services in Huawei, and Huawei doesn't recognize a debug version of your app as a proper app, it destroys all services maybe cause of security reasons ...

Installing it properly over Play Store helps!

Answer (score 1):

Because the `PendingIntent` scheduled is a token associated with your app, and if the app is forcefully killed, stopped or hibernated, it will be removed by the system. You can set it up again in `onResume` or `onCreate` when the user starts your app again.

Comment: but if i want a service which checks each minute about an update even if the app is destroy, how can i handle this? (e.g WhatsApp)

Comment: Are the SERVICES killed, when the user swipes the app off in the app switcher or only when he goes to settings > application manager and closes the app there

Comment: Swiping off the app from recent tasks won't stop service from starting again if START_STICKY is used. Whereas if you use a task killer or hibernation app, the service will stop. Service Whatsapp's is  also stops when it is hibernated or "killed".

Comment: Okay then it has to be Huawei which modified this default behavior because it was the only thing we did

Comment: the PendingIntent will not be removed by the system. Thats the purpose of it

Comment: You are welcome to set up a PendingIntent and then hibernate the app.

Comment: "A PendingIntent itself is simply a reference to a token maintained by the system describing the original data used to retrieve it. This means that, even if its owning application's process is killed, the PendingIntent itself will remain usable from other processes that have been given it."

Comment: I've read the documentation, but I've tested force closing the apps and hibernating them many times, and this does result in removal of PendingIntent. I guess being killed is written here in some other context. But you are very welcome to experiment with this and prove me wrong.

Comment: @Piyush disregarding what exactly happens to the pendingintent, you are correct in saying that force closing an app removes any alarms that it had set